# How to create Stellar Muxed accounts using java-stellar-sdk

Tags: stellar-core, stellar-sdk

How to create Stellar Muxed accounts using java-stellar-sdk-0.31.0.jar,
I want to create Muxed account with id `1` from custodian account
`GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE`

attached my code, I get result but seems very long muxed account, can you please help on this?

```
 public static String createMuxedAccount(String custacc) throws Exception {

        MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519 accountMed25519 = new MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519();
        accountMed25519.setEd25519(new Uint256(custacc.getBytes()));
        accountMed25519.setId(new Uint64(1L));

        MuxedAccount muxedAccount = new MuxedAccount();
        muxedAccount.setDiscriminant(CryptoKeyType.KEY_TYPE_MUXED_ED25519);
        muxedAccount.setMed25519(accountMed25519);

        AccountConverter accountConverter = AccountConverter.enableMuxed();
        String muxedAccountrep = accountConverter.decode(muxedAccount);
        System.out.println(muxedAccountrep);
         return muxedAccountrep;

    }
```

```
        String destination = createMuxedAccount("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE");

MBDUETKIKRMDMVSPJFEVGNCGJZIVGTKUKNLVMSCDJVLEGSSYKRKE4WCUJFMTGU2CLBETKSZUJZGEIQ2UKY2UGSSMLJCQAAAAAAAAAAABNKZA
```

when I use that generated Muxed account the transaction fail:

```
tx_failed
[op_no_destination]
```

```java
package com.example.DemoGraphQL.services;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.stellar.sdk.*;
import org.stellar.sdk.Memo;
import org.stellar.sdk.Transaction;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.AccountResponse;
import org.stellar.sdk.responses.SubmitTransactionResponse;
import org.stellar.sdk.xdr.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;


@Service
public class StellarServices {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        sendTransaction();
    }

 

    public static String createMuxedAccount(String custacc) throws Exception {

        MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519 accountMed25519 = new MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519();
        accountMed25519.setEd25519(new Uint256(custacc.getBytes()));
        accountMed25519.setId(new Uint64(1L));


        MuxedAccount muxedAccount = new MuxedAccount();
        muxedAccount.setDiscriminant(CryptoKeyType.KEY_TYPE_MUXED_ED25519);
        muxedAccount.setMed25519(accountMed25519);

        AccountConverter accountConverter = AccountConverter.enableMuxed();
        String muxedAccountrep = accountConverter.decode(muxedAccount);

        return muxedAccountrep;

    }

    public static void sendTransaction() throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server("https://horizon-testnet.stellar.org");

        KeyPair source = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed("SC3TVXXRGKXX5ATKLNLZZGHS642MAKFMSU7CYTY55XE3NNBFLJS45TXY");
        String destination = createMuxedAccount("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE");


        AccountResponse sourceAccount = server.accounts().account(source.getAccountId());

// Start building the transaction.
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction.Builder( sourceAccount, Network.TESTNET)
                .addOperation(new PaymentOperation.Builder(destination, new AssetTypeNative(), "10").build())
                // A memo allows you to add your own metadata to a transaction. It's
                // optional and does not affect how Stellar treats the transaction.
                .addMemo(Memo.text("Test Transaction"))
                // Wait a maximum of three minutes for the transaction
                .setTimeout(180)
                // Set the amount of lumens you're willing to pay per operation to submit your transaction
                .setBaseFee(Transaction.MIN_BASE_FEE)
                .build();
// Sign the transaction to prove you are actually the person sending it.
        transaction.sign(source);

// And finally, send it off to Stellar!
        try {
            SubmitTransactionResponse response = server.submitTransaction(transaction);
            System.out.println(response.getHash());
            System.out.println(response.getExtras().getResultCodes().getTransactionResultCode());
            System.out.println(response.getExtras().getResultCodes().getOperationsResultCodes());
            System.out.println(response.getExtras().getResultXdr());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong!");
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        }
    }
}
```

There is no clear Java example , like in javascript it's very easy like following

```javascript
 new sdk.MuxedAccount(custodianAcc, "1")
```

or

```javascript
   const StellarBase = require("stellar-base");

  let baseAccount = new StellarBase.Account("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE", '1');
  const mux = new StellarBase.MuxedAccount(baseAccount, '0');

  console.log(JSON.stringify(mux))
```

and response is :

```json
{"account":{"_accountId":"GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE","sequence":"1"},"_muxedXdr":{"_switch":{"name":"keyTypeMuxedEd25519","value":256},"_arm":"med25519","_value":{"_attributes":{"id":{"low":0,"high":0,"unsigned":true},"ed25519":{"type":"Buffer","data":[88,121,223,213,114,17,46,21,176,147,39,43,84,226,101,68,155,206,109,188,209,141,200,55,71,85,198,172,98,157,122,36]}}}},"_mAddress":"MBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CIAAAAAAAAAAAAASPS","_id":"0"}
```

in Python it's also clear

```python
account_id = "GAQAA5L65LSYH7CQ3VTJ7F3HHLGCL3DSLAR2Y47263D56MNNGHSQSTVY"
account_muxed_id = 1234
account_muxed = "MAQAA5L65LSYH7CQ3VTJ7F3HHLGCL3DSLAR2Y47263D56MNNGHSQSAAAAAAAAAAE2LP26"
# generate account_muxed
muxed = MuxedAccount(account=account_id, account_muxed_id=1234)
```

I tried to follow js & the java sdk unit tests documentation:
here :
1- https://developers.stellar.org/docs/glossary/muxed-accounts/#what-happens-if-i-get-errors-when-using-muxed-accounts

2- https://github.com/stellar/stellar-protocol/blob/master/core/cap-0027.md

3- https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/test/java/org/stellar/sdk/OperationTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the Muxed account ID with the length that looks normal `MBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CIAAAAAAAAAAAAEC6S`

Solved by:
changing `accountMed25519.setEd25519(new Uint256(custacc.getBytes()));` to

`accountMed25519.setEd25519(new Uint256(KeyPair.fromAccountId(custacc).getPublicKey()));`  on the method `createMuxedAccount` ;

here is the new method body:

```java
 public static String createMuxedAccount(String custacc) throws Exception {

        MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519 accountMed25519 = new MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519();

        accountMed25519.setEd25519(new Uint256(KeyPair.fromAccountId(custacc).getPublicKey()));
        accountMed25519.setId(new Uint64(1L));


        MuxedAccount muxedAccount = new MuxedAccount();
        muxedAccount.setDiscriminant(CryptoKeyType.KEY_TYPE_MUXED_ED25519);
        muxedAccount.setMed25519(accountMed25519);

        AccountConverter accountConverter = AccountConverter.enableMuxed();
        String muxedAccountrep = accountConverter.decode(muxedAccount);

        System.out.println(muxedAccountrep);

        return muxedAccountrep;

    }
```

I found there are many ways to generate muxed accounts based on what you want to use: from secret, public key string, KeyPair etc..

```java
   KeyPair keyPairFromSecret = KeyPair.fromSecretSeed("SC3TVXXRGKXX5ATKLNLZZGHS642MAKFMSU7CYTY55XE3NNBFLJS45TXY");
        KeyPair keyPairFromAccountID = KeyPair.fromAccountId("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE");
        Uint256 uint256 = new Uint256();
        uint256.setUint256(KeyPair.fromAccountId("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE").getPublicKey());
        // need to copy StrKey.java from stellar SDK + Google  Juava
        Uint256 uint2561FromAccountid = StrKey.encodeToXDRMuxedAccount("GBMHTX6VOIIS4FNQSMTSWVHCMVCJXTTNXTIY3SBXI5K4NLDCTV5CJLZE").getEd25519();

        MuxedAccount muxedAccount = new MuxedAccount();
        muxedAccount.setDiscriminant(CryptoKeyType.KEY_TYPE_MUXED_ED25519);
        MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519 med = new MuxedAccount.MuxedAccountMed25519();

// all of these are working
        med.setEd25519(uint2561FromAccountid); 
        med.setEd25519(uint256);
        med.setEd25519(keyPairFromAccountID.getXdrPublicKey().getEd25519());
        med.setEd25519(keyPairFromSecret.getXdrPublicKey().getEd25519());

        med.setId(new Uint64(1l));
        muxedAccount.setMed25519(med);
        AccountConverter accountConverter = AccountConverter.enableMuxed();
        String muxedAccountrep = accountConverter.decode(muxedAccount);
        System.out.println(muxedAccountrep);
```